# Querying and count distinct contacts and group them by month

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

this is my first post an d I hope I am fulfilling the guidelines.
Beforehand: I am a complete beginner with SQL and used it roughly in the past.

Here is my issue:

Prerequisite:
I have a table with contacts and timestamps, e.g.

| contact_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| contact_001 | 2022-01-03 |
| contact_001 | 2022-01-16 |
| contact_002 | 2022-01-03 |
| contact_003 | 2022-01-05 |
| contact_002 | 2017-04-27 |
| contact_003 | 2017-04-27 |

Expected outcome:
I'd like to have a table which counts(!) the unique(!) contacts based on the contact_id per month and write it in a table so I get something like this:

| Month | contactCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 3 |
| 2017-04 | 2 |

Can someone provide me with a schema how to query that?

I really appreciate your help and I apologize if this is not the right way or place to put that question.

Please see my explanation above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL and its own ways of handling dates. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am using google-bigquery.

Comment: Here are the docs on date functions for Google BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions. `FORMAT_DATE` and `DATE_TRUNC` look promising. Read the answers and modify the queries by applying the appropriate BigQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

In a general sense it would be as simple as follows...

```
SELECT
  the_month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id)
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  the_month
ORDER BY
  the_month
```

How to get the month form your timestamp, however, depends on the SQL dialect you're using.

For example;

- SQL Server = `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [timestamp]), 0)`
- SQL Server = `DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH([timestamp], -1))`
- MySQL = `DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-01')`
- Oracle = `TRUNC(timestamp, 'MM')`

So, which RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

- SQL Server

```sql
SELECT
  FORMAT(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM') AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id) AS contactCount
FROM table
GROUP BY FORMAT(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY 1
```

- MySQL

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m') AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id) AS contactCount
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks guys! You helped me a lot. I was not aware that `COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id)` works with `"GROUP BY"` at the same time as I assumed that unique entries are only considered when they first appeared.

Here is what I finally used:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', date) AS month,
COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id) AS contactCount
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY 1
```